# Extract Key/Values from Terraform Map Variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to extract both left and right values from the terraform map variable but couldn't extract the left value. Below is my code :-

```
variables.tf
  variable "notebook" {
    type = "map"
    default = {
    "01" = "a@a.com"
    "02" = "b@a.com"
    "03" = "c@a.com"
    "04" = "d@a.com"
    ......
  }
}
```

Below is my module in  main.tf

```
 module "instance" {
   instance_ip = ["1.1.1.x", "1.1.2.y", "1.1.1.z","1.1.2.p"]
   dns         = ["x", "y", "z","p"]
   name        = ["a", "b", "c",  "d"]
 }
```

The output should be as below :-

```
 module "instance" {
   instance_ip = ["1.1.1.01", "1.1.2.02", "1.1.1.03","1.1.2.04" and so on]
   dns         = ["01", "02", "03","04" and so on]
   name        = ["a@a.com", "b@a.com", "c@a.com", "d@a.com and so on]
 }
```

Any suggestions. I tried lookup on variable but getting only the a@a.com and not the Key's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `keys` and `values` functions for this:

```
# terraform 0.12
module "instance" {
  instance_ip = ["1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[0]}", "1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[1]}", "1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[2]}"]
  dns         = keys(var.notebook)
  name        = values(var.notebook)
}

# terraform 0.11
module "instance" {
  instance_ip = ["1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[0]}", "1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[1]}", "1.1.1.${keys(var.notebook)[2]}"]
  dns         = ["${keys(var.notebook)}"]
  name        = ["${values(var.notebook)}"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt but in my case the values will be more than 10/20+. In that case I need the substitution in one line instead of writing for each. Is there any way we can generalize this for many values with even/odd. I updated my question as per the same. Please check once.